# jQuery find data attribute value

Tags: jquery, html

Hello i have a table with Data attribute and i what to find if the data attribute has the same value.

```
 <tr style="height: 40px;" cart-item="" data-line-weight="10" data-total-lien="10" data-item-barcode="3434" class="tablerow" id="rowid1">
```

I am trying to find the TR that has  data-item-barcode is equal "3434"
 and change the value of the input filed that is inside the TR that was found

```
<tr style="height: 40px;" cart-item="" data-line-weight="10" data-total-lien="10" data-item-barcode="3434" class="tablerow" id="rowid1">
<td width="210" class="text-left" style="line-height:30px;">
<span style="text-transform: uppercase;">food</span></td>
<td width="130" class="text-center" style="line-height:30px;">10</td>
<td width="145" class="text-center"><div class="input-group input-group-sm">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default item-reduce" type="button" id="reduce1">-</button>
</span>
<input type="number" name="QNY[]" value="1" class="form-control qny" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3" id="qny1">
<span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default item-add" type="button" id="addB1">+</button></span></div></td></tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: Question is not clear ...can you please clarify what exactly you are looking at

Comment: Edit Then query

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well what you'd like to achieve this should work:

```
$('tr[data-item-barcode="3434"] input[type="number"]').val('YOUR VALUE');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what are you trying to achieve but I guess it goes like this, if I matched tr with that attribute (data-item-barcode=3434) I want to update input with some value?

So, here it goes:

```js
var trMatched = $("tr[data-item-barcode=3434]");
if(trMatched.length > 0){
  $("input", trMatched).val(20);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
  <tr style="height: 40px;" cart-item="" data-line-weight="10" data-total-lien="10" data-item-barcode="3434" class="tablerow" id="rowid1">
    <td width="210" class="text-left" style="line-height:30px;">
      <span style="text-transform: uppercase;">food</span>
    </td>
    <td width="130" class="text-center" style="line-height:30px;">10</td>
    <td width="145" class="text-center">
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default item-reduce" type="button" id="reduce1">-</button>
</span>
        <input type="number" name="QNY[]" value="1" class="form-control qny" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3" id="qny1">
        <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default item-add" type="button" id="addB1">+</button></span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</html>
```